# An application of \foreach command in TikZ to generate labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like ask you to help me solve the following application of `\foreach` of the TikZ package. By means of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\small
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
\fill (\x,0) circle (2pt);

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
\node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {\x};

\foreach \x in {3.25,3.5,...,4.75}
\fill (\x,0) circle (0.5pt);

\foreach \x in {5,...,8}
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}
{
\fill (\x,0) circle (2pt);
\node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {$n+\y$};
}

\foreach \x in {8.25,8.5,...,9.75}
\fill (\x,0) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I obtain the picture below:
[image: output]
where arguments of `\y` are stacked one upon another. What I aim at are `n+1, ..., n+4` labels above the right-hand dots. But I do not know how to tell TikZ to make `\y` argument dependent on `\x` in this way. I will be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for nested loops, you can use just a simple `\foreach` and the `count=` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}\small
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
\fill (\x,0) circle (2pt);

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
\node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {\x};

\foreach \x in {3.25,3.5,...,4.75}
\fill (\x,0) circle (0.5pt);

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {5,...,8}
{
\fill (\x,0) circle (2pt);
\node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {$n+\xi$};
}

\foreach \x in {8.25,8.5,...,9.75}
\fill (\x,0) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of the option and could not find a hint in the TikZ guide.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, you can reduce the number of `foreach` loops as follows

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-4);}] in {0,...,3,5,6,...,8}
    {
        \fill (\x,0) circle (2pt);
        \ifnum\x<4
            \node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {\x};
        \else
            \node[above=2pt] at (\x,0) {$n+\xi$};
        \fi
    }
    \foreach \x in {3.25,3.5,...,4.75,8.25,8.5,...,9.75}
    \fill (\x,0) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This can probably be improved yet further as;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-4);}] in {0,...,3,5,6,...,8}
    {
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,label={[above=2pt]90:{\ifnum\x<4\relax\x\else$n+\xi$\fi}}]
          (n-\x) at (\x,0) {};
    }
\draw[loosely dotted] (n-3) -- (n-5) (n-8) -- ++(2cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Very nice example! I am a TikZ beginner so this helps me a lot to improve my understanding of the package.

Comment: @percusse, I tip my hat to you, sir :) truly marvellous, and extremely gracious of you to make an edit ;)

Comment: Nothing compared to your kind words :)

Comment: Could you explain why is 90: put into the code of percusse? With or without it the resulting picture is the same.